# make querySelectorAll a live nodelist

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I am using Swiper.js to create multiple sliders on the same page.

For a program I am writing I am trying to acces the second swiper on the page and moving it to a certain slide based on parameters I am giving it. I can acces the first swiper using 
`var mySwiper = document.querySelector('.swiper-container').swiper;` 
I have tried accessing the second swiper via 
`var mySwiper = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-container')[1].swiper;` 
If I console log `mySwiper`, it returns the same on both methods.

I have also tried using `var mySwiper = document.querySelector('.swiper-container:nth-child(2)');`, but that returned `null` instead of the swiper information.

`getElementsByClassName` also returns the proper values but doesn't let the `nextSlide()` function execute.

I want to use `mySwiper.slideNext();` on both of them, but it only works on `querySelector`, not a selected `querySelectorAll`.

The problem is that querySelector is live, while querySelectorAll is a static nodeList. I can solve this if I can make querySelectorAll live, however, I have not found any documentation on it.

My full code:

```
if (condition1) {
     var mySwiper = document.querySelector('.swiper-container').swiper;
     var swiper = value1;
     setSwiper(mySwiper, swiper);
}
else if (condition2){
    var swiper = customObject['option2'];
    var mySwiper = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-container')[1].swiper;
    setSwiper((mySwiper, swiper));
}

function setSwiper(selected, arg){
    if(arg == "B"){
        selected.slideNext();
    } else if(arg == "C"){
        selected.slideNext();
        selected.slideNext();
    }
}
```

The functions are run without interference.

Comment: You're reassigning the `mySwiper` variable. Should rename it to `mySwiper2`, for example, and then you have to call `slideNext()` on both instances, i.e.`mySwiper.slideNext(); mySwiper2.slideNext();`

Comment: Sorry, have not clarified that both are in seperate ```if-statements``` and refrence to a function that takes the mySwiper as an argument, together with an argument that causes the slideNext() to be used a certain ammount of times.

Comment: You can not “make it” live (other than by calling it again explicitly every time you need it.) If you only need this for a class selector here - then use `getElementsByClassName` instead, that _is_ “live”.

Comment: (Not sure live vs not live is your actual problem here though. This should come with a proper [mre] to show us what you are actually doing, instead of just showing single lines of code that lack context.)

Comment: Added the code, my apologies

Answer (score 0):

In the second condition I called `setSwiper((mySwiper, swiper));`, which should be `setSwiper(mySwiper, swiper);` removing the excess brackets fixed my code, together with utilising `getElementsByClassName`.